# numpy Matlab equivalent of `bitxor` between to vectors of different sizes WITHOUT loop

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, xor

Here is the matlab code :

```
A=[1,2,3,4];
B=[5,3];
bitxor(A,B')
```

it returns :

```
ans =

     4     7     6     1
     2     1     0     7
```

How do I do that with numpy without a loop ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `np.bitwise_xor.outer(B, A)`

Alternatively, `A ^ B[:,np.newaxis]` works, which is identical for 1D arrays. `B[:,np.newaxis]` produces an array with shape `(2, 1)`, which broadcasts against `A` with shape `(4,)` to produce an output of shape `(2, 4)`, as desired.

Comment: Amazing response, I love it :) !

Comment: Do you have any documentation that is explaining the second notation in a simple way ?

Comment: Updated. `^` in python is the same as `np.bitwise_xor`.

Comment: I must precise I haven't done linear algebra since 1995 and the pb. is that I'm new to numpy. I add read one or two docs but I couldn't understand anything about broadcasting :(

Comment: It seems that `A^B.reshape(2,1)` works but why does `A^B.T` not ?

Comment: I read the `np.newaxis` increases the dimensions of an array :


A is a 1D array and `B[:,np.newaxis]` becomes a 2D array

Why is this necessary to do the `^` when Matlab only needs to transpose B ?

Comment: It seems that `A^B[:,None]` does the same :)

Comment: Of course you need `^`, because `^` is the xor operation! `np.newaxis == None`, which is why that works.

Comment: I see I miss wrote my question :

Why is the `[:,np.newaxis]` operation necessary when Matlab only needs to transpose the second vector ?

Comment: Because in matlab `A` is 2D, but in numpy it is 1D. Transposing a 1D array isn't a well-defined operation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148084/discussion-between-sebma-and-eric).

Comment: I thought (2,) and (2,1) were both 1d arrays (vectors), but apparently it's not true. Thanks for your explanation.